# Not being able to provide custom authentication provider for the spring security

Tags: java, spring, security, spring-mvc, spring-security

I want to have a custom Authentication Provider for spring security and i have implemented it like this

```
@Component
public class ApiCustomAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {
@Override
public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {

System.out.println("ahsgdvjasdhgjasjdh");
return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken("aman", "12345");
}
@Override
public boolean supports(Class<?> authentication) {
    return (UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.class.isAssignableFrom(authentication));


   }
}
```

Right now i don't have any logic as i just want to see if spring security is actually using this authentication provider .

i have my security config file as

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
//@ImportResource("classpath:/security/spring_saml_sso_security.xml")

public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
/*@Autowired
MetadataGeneratorFilter metadataGeneratorFilter; 
@Autowired
FilterChainProxy samlFilter; 
@Autowired
SAMLEntryPoint samlEntryPoint;
*/

@Autowired
private CustomUserDetailsService customUserDetailsService;




@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

     try {
        http
         .csrf().disable()
         .authorizeRequests()
         .antMatchers("/static/**").permitAll()
         .antMatchers("/settings/api/**").permitAll()
         .antMatchers("/api/**").permitAll()
         .anyRequest().authenticated()
         .and()
         .formLogin()
         .loginPage("/login").permitAll()
         .loginProcessingUrl("/login")
        // .usernameParameter("username").passwordParameter("password")
         .defaultSuccessUrl("/index",true)
         .and()
         .httpBasic();
    //   .defaultSuccessUrl("/", true);
} catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        System.out.println("sadhiasdniaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa:");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
@Bean
public ApiCustomAuthenticationProvider apiCustomAuthenticationProvider() {
    return new ApiCustomAuthenticationProvider();
    }
}
```

i want to know if this

```
@Bean
public ApiCustomAuthenticationProvider apiCustomAuthenticationProvider() {
    return new ApiCustomAuthenticationProvider();
```

is the correct way of telling spring security to use the custom authentication manager .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add this in Spring security config:

```
@Autowired
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.authenticationProvider(new ApiCustomAuthenticationProvider());
}
```

or

```
auth.authenticationProvider(apiCustomAuthenticationProvider())
```

And as a reminder, if you return token :

`UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken("aman", "12345")`,

spring will not give authorization to user. Instead you need to assign role :

```
List<GrantedAuthority> grantedAuths = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();
grantedAuths.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_USER"));
UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken("aman", "12345",grantedAuths) ;
```

As stated above,you are giving user `ROLE_USER` and then user can use all authenticated page.

Hope its help.

Comment: Thanks it worked . Can you tell me a source where i can find appropriate counterpart to xml conventions . I searched and i was only able to find that @Bean  one

Comment: Welcome,please accept the answer to help others. Do you want to create xml instead of javaconfig?

Comment: i did . But i am new and my upvotes wouldn't show as i don't have enough reputation points. no i don't . I just want a guide where java config counterparts of xml configuration are present

Comment: I mean the right tick,its below the downvote. you can click that tick to show this answer as accepted. Actually I learn mostly on spring doc here: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/

Comment: sorry to bother you but after i did it what you said and  everything worked but now as soon as i autowire the class that would help me in authenticationg and use it i get the following error                                                       java.lang.NullPointerException
 org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:192)

can you tell me why's this happening .Do i need a custom Usernamepassword aythentication filter as well

Comment: If you autowired bean in CustomAuthenticationProvider, you need to declare all effecting bean in security context, the reason you get null because spring cannot find the bean in security context, and security context is different from application context.

Comment: yes that's correct i guess .Thanks . So i know how to declare bean of customauthentificationprovider but how do i declare a bean of some other class ? will the syntax be same                          @Bean
public Class_name class_name() {
    return new Class_name();

Comment: Yup,declaring the bean is same as long as you include `@Bean` .